# Change linker order Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

I'm trying to port an agent simulator (Artificial Intelligence) used in my University to GNU/Linux and I have a little problem: this project is used under Code::Blocks and I don't know very much about this IDE. I have some "undefined reference" errors and I don't know how to solve them.

This is the linking order that Code::Blocks uses:

```
g++  -o Agent .objs/agent.o .objs/environment.o .objs/evaluator.o .objs/GUI.o .objs/include/glui.o .objs/include/glui_bitmap_img_data.o .objs/include/glui_bitmaps.o .objs/include/glui_button.o .objs/include/glui_column.o .objs/include/glui_control.o .objs/include/glui_edittext.o .objs/include/glui_filebrowser.o .objs/include/glui_list.o .objs/include/glui_node.o .objs/include/glui_panel.o .objs/include/glui_radio.o .objs/include/glui_rollout.o .objs/include/glui_scrollbar.o .objs/include/glui_spinner.o .objs/include/glui_statictext.o .objs/include/glui_string.o .objs/include/glui_window.o .objs/main.o .objs/random_num_gen.o   lib/libglu32.a lib/libglui.a lib/libglut32.a lib/libopengl32.a lib/libopenglut.a
```

These .o and .a files exist in the filesystem, obviously, so I only have one idea: there might be missing `-I` in the linker order? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Right click the opened project and press build options. You should see the objects linked. Use the up and down arrows to move them in whatever order you need.

Comment: Strange... these libraries are in that window! I have ordered them but I have the same error... a lot of undefined reference for OpenGL functions... the .a files are in the correct folder, too :(. The same project compiles correctly in Windows using MinGW...

Comment: Pretty sure on linux it is mesa and not opengl32. Either that or the order is still wrong.